# Copy files with a chunked stream causes the files to be different sizes due to last read

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

Could someone be kind enough to explain how I get my files the same size after copying it using a chunked stream? I presume it is because the last chunk still has a `buffer` size of **2048** so it is putting empty bytes at the end, but I am unsure how I would adjust the last read?

**Original size:** 15.1 MB (**15,835,745** bytes)
**New size:** 15.1 MB (**15,837,184** bytes)

```
        static FileStream incomingFile;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            incomingFile = new FileStream(
             @"D:\temp\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png",
               FileMode.Create, 
               FileAccess.Write);

            FileCopy();
        }

        private static void FileCopy()
        {

            using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(@"D:\temp\test.png"))
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

                var chunkCount = source.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < (chunkCount / 2048) + 1; i++)
                {
                    source.Position = i * 2048;
                    source.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
                    WriteFile(buffer);
                }
                incomingFile.Close();
            }

        }
        private static void WriteFile(byte[] buffer)
        {

            incomingFile.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *last* `buffer` read does not necessary contain exactly `2048` bytes (it can well be *incomplete*). Imagine, we have a file of `5000` bytes; in this case will read **3** chunks: **2** complete and **1** incomplete

```
2048 
2048  
 904 the last incomplete buffer
```

Code:

```
        using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(@"D:\temp\test.png"))
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            var chunkCount = source.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < (chunkCount / 2048) + 1; i++)
            {
                source.Position = i * 2048;

                // size - number of actually bytes read 
                int size = source.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

                // if we bytes to write, do it
                if (size > 0)
                    WriteFile(buffer, size);
            }
            incomingFile.Close();
        }

        ... 

        private static void WriteFile(byte[] buffer, int size = -1) 
        {
           incomingFile.Write(buffer, 0, size < 0 ? buffer.Length : size);
        }
```

In your case you write `15837184 == 7733 * 2048` bytes (`7733` *complete* chunks) when you should write `15835745 == 7732 * 2048 + 609` bytes - `7732` *complete* chunks and the last *incomplete* one of `609` bytes